# Set height of <li> based of div height

Tags: html, css, html-lists

hope you can help me.
I am trying to create a navigation with a variable amount of list elements. Now I want to automatically set the height of the list elements based on the height of the surrounding div element, and the number of list elements that are in the div. Is there a way to do so, or can I only do it the other way around, by simply not giving the div a height value, but rather give the list elements a fixed height?

Hope you can help me.

```
#nav ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

#nav{
    margin-top: 30px;
    width: 19%;
    background-color: red;
    float:left;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}

#nav ul li{
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
background-color: yellow;
height: 50px;
margin-top: 20px;
line-height: 50px;
border-bottom: 1px solid black;
border-left: 1px solid black;
transform: rotate(20deg);
}
```

Comment: Can you please show the code snippet here or on fiddle or on codepen?

Comment: Hi there, welcome to SO. Could you please add code snippets of what you actually tried so far? It will make the question much easier to understand. I recommend you read the [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. It has precious advices about writing a good question, and will make answers better too.

Comment: there isnt much to show tho, since i am using fixed values because i havent found a solution yet, and ignore the transform so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below code,it will definitely work

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="change" style="height:200px;border:1px solid black">
<ul>
<li>HI</li>
<li>Hello</li>
<li>Bye</li>
<li>Byesdfsd</li>
<li>sdfsd</li>
<li>sdfsd</li>
</ul>
</div>
<script>
var height=document.getElementById("change").style.height;
height=height.replace("px","");
var lis=document.getElementsByTagName("li");
for(var i=0;i<lis.length;i++){
 lis[i].style.height=(parseInt(height))/(parseInt(lis.length))+"px";
 console.log("getting height "+lis[i].style.height);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

- So you can give the height of the div in a class or in the inline style,but you will have to change the code accordingly in the js part for fetching the height of the div.
- I have got the li tags and then depending on their number i have divided the height of the enclosing div by the number of list tags

Comment: that is working perfectly for me needs. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

So basically what you want is that if the div is 100px high and you have 4 items in the list, each item should be 25px high, and if you have 5 items then each should be 20px high. Is it correct?

In this case, if you don't want to resort to javascript, you can use flexbox.
Here, javascript is only used to dinamically add items to the menu in order to demonstrate flexbox behavior:

```js
var menuEl = document.getElementById('menu');

document.getElementById('addMenuItemBtn').onclick = function () {
 var numberOfItems = menuEl.childElementCount;
  // create a new menu item
  var newListElement = document.createElement('li');
  newListElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Menu item ' + (numberOfItems + 1)));
  newListElement.setAttribute('class', 'item');
  // append the new item
  menuEl.appendChild(newListElement);
}

document.getElementById('removeMenuItemBtn').onclick = function () {
 var numberOfItems = menuEl.childElementCount;
  if (numberOfItems > 1) {
   // if there are at least 2 items, remove the last item
    var lastItemIndex = numberOfItems - 1;
    var lastItem = menuEl.children[lastItemIndex];
    lastItem.remove();
  }
}
```

```css
.container {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 320px;
  height: 240px; /* enough for 6 items with a height of 40px */
  background-color: #DDD;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.item {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: 30px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="container" id="menu">
  <li class="item">Menu item 1</li>
  <li class="item">Menu item 2</li>
</ul>
<input type="button" value="Add menu item" id="addMenuItemBtn">
<input type="button" value="Remove menu item" id="removeMenuItemBtn">
```

Since the container is 240px high and items have a minimum height of 40px (flex-basis: 30px + margin: 5px), there is enough space for 6 items. If you add more than 6 items, the extra elements will overflow.

You can read more about flexbox in [this article](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) on css-tricks.com.
You'll likely want to change a lot of things in my snippet, it's just a proof of concept!
Just keep in mind that some old browsers don't support it, or support it with
a legacy syntax.

Comment: yes thats what im trying to do, but since the amount of elements if not fixed im having trouble setting the correct height values